# How do i search a key value into a multidimensional array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on the front end side of an app that handles a data warehouse, so i have a lot of arrays with field names and data types.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
["CODART"]["S"],
["DESCART"]["A"],
["EXST"]["S"]
```

and i want to search by the key and get the other value like
"CODART" and i get "S"

Thanks in advance

Cannot use jquery, only pure JS.

I created my array just like this:

```
selex2.push(Element, dataType);
```

now i want to search for the first value to get the second.

Comment: That's not a valid array?

Comment: Please share a syntactically viable code example.

Comment: Edited my question, thanks in advance

Comment: maybe if you add the code that populates the array we could follow along.

Comment: Element and dataType are just a couple of vars with string values. Thanks.

Comment: @rogerluces Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess with multidimensional array you meant something like the following.

```
[
    ["KEY", "VALUE"],
    ["KEY2", "VALUE2"],
]
```

First of this is not the best type of data structure to work with in JS. However, to find `VALUE` or `VALUE2` based on `KEY` or `KEY2` you would need the following code.

```
// Find the array where 'KEY' is our first value.
const potential = array.find(([key]) => key === 'KEY');
```

In the variable `potential` you would now have `["KEY", "VALUE"]`. If you're absolutely save, that there is a value for the key you're searching for, you can extract the value with the following.

```
const value = potential[1];
```

If you're not sure, you should check if `potential` is defined. You can do this with the following.

```
if (potential) {
  // You're save, potential is defined and you can extract the value.
} else {
  // Watch out! Potential is undefined and trying to extract the value
  // will lead to an error.
}
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, it worked for me.

Comment: @rogerluces Great, glad I could help. Could you mark my answer as accepted, so that other people having similar issues can benefit too? Thanks in advance!